# qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSLv2_client_method

Tags: c++, qt, ubuntu, qt5

I am trying to make POST request to remote server. Here is my code:

```
void LoginWindow::on_login_pushButton_clicked()
{
    const QString url = ui->server_lineEdit->text ();
    const QString username = ui->username_lineEdit->text ();
    const QString password = ui->password_lineEdit->text ();
    QNetworkAccessManager mAccessManager;
    QNetworkRequest request(QUrl(url + "/api/auth/"));

    QUrlQuery urlQuery;
    urlQuery.addQueryItem ("username", username);
    urlQuery.addQueryItem ("password", password);

    QUrl params;
    params.setQuery (urlQuery);

    QNetworkReply* reply = mAccessManager.post (request, params.toEncoded ());

    connect (reply, &QNetworkReply::readyRead, [reply]() {
        qDebug()  << "Ready to read from reply";
    });
    connect (reply, &QNetworkReply::sslErrors, [this] (QList<QSslError> error) {
        qWarning () << "Ssl error: " << error;
    });

}
```

When I clicked the login button nothing happens, except a message in application output tab.

```
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSLv2_client_method
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSLv2_server_method
```

I checked the remote server log, there was no request from qt client.

I am using ubuntu 16.04 and Qt 5.9 . I also followed [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/711863/installing-qt-5-5-1-on-ubuntu-14-04-throws-qt-network-ssl-error-on-terminal) solution, still no luck

Comment: Do you have OpenSSL installed on your machine as in the solution link?

Comment: I also had that problem with openssl in windows too. you should install openssl in ubuntu. `sudo apt-get install libssl-dev`

Comment: @saeed Azeem both packages are already installed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sslv2 is completely disabled in newer distributions ,  install libssl-0.98 from [launchpad](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/trusty/+package/libssl0.9.8) by `dpkg`.

Open a terminal, go to the extracted folder and run:

> sudo dpkg -i file.deb
>
> sudo apt-get install -f

You can use **QSsl::SecureProtocols** to enable the SSL versions which are considered secure as of the Qt release.

Comment: Still facing the problem.

Comment: did you restart your PC

Comment: whats result of QSslSocket::supportsSsl()

Comment: it returns true

Comment: let me work on it , I face your issue now on kubuntu 17.04 and I am looking for a solution now

Comment: what is result of `QSslSocket::sslLibraryBuildVersionString()`

Comment: "OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013"